# Where did I go wrong in creating a new tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, minecraft, sub-tags

When I asked this question: [Using scoreboard objectives as arguments for commands](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/163094/using-scoreboard-objectives-as-arguments-for-commands), I created the tag [minecraft-commands](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-commands), since I thought that such a tag would be useful now and in the future (especially since the Minecraft command system has received significant upgrades recently).

However, the tag was removed from my post twice. What should I have done to introduce this tag?

Note that I have suggested a tag wiki for it, and I was notified that it has been approved, though I don't see it on the info page yet.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In general, we tend to only tag for the title of the game in question. There's a host of reasons for this, both historical and practical that aren't worth getting into too deeply - (the short version is that it's a combination of the tag limit, the fact that natural tag-death is Not A Thing at Arqade as it is on other SE sites, and that generic tags like [mechanics](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mechanics) or [console-commands](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/console-commands) just wouldn't be useful in any real way) - but the end result is that we tend to only tag based on the name of the game unless there's significant community consensus here on Meta that we want to chop things up further -  which happens with exceptional rarity.

Comment: What about [tag:minecraft-redstone]? It seems to be the same type of tag.

Comment: `unless there's significant community consensus here on Meta that we want to chop things up further` - It's rare, but it does happen, and Redstone is the banner example.

Comment: I see. As someone using Stack Overflow primarily, it just makes sense to have more specific tags on a question. It makes it easier to search for questions on a specific topic. If you have some links that expand on said "historical and practical reasons", they would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Part of the trick is that if someone creates a tag on SO and no other questions use it ever, *it goes away on it's own*. Because of the special case of using game titles as tags here, and sometimes having only one question about a game, that system just doesn't work *[as in, it's disabled entirely on Arqade --bp]*, so we're aggressive about not creating tags that aren't going to see *widespread* usage.